# Hadoop cluster browser not working :site can't be reached

Tags: kubernetes, hadoop, browser

I'm trying to open the brower of hadoop cluster with using this url : `localhost:8088` but it showning : This site can't be reached.

i run `kubectl get services` :
[image]

Hadoop is installed on a pod on kubernetes(minikube), i followed this tutoriel :

https://medium.com/@rewelle/d%C3%A9ploiement-dune-architecture-compl%C3%A8te-big-data-avec-kubernetes-570eaa0e627

Thanks for help

Comment: none of your service is exposed over 8088 if you have port-forwarded any service please provide command and details.

Comment: Linked post does not seem to say anything about port 8088... Rather than constantly struggling with this, I'd highly recommend not running Hadoop inside containers at all. Especially not YARN. Ozone or MinIO are HDFS compatible filesystems that can be used instead and are easier to deploy in k8s